# Is this correct : $x,y,z,t$ natural numbers If : $x\mid y+z+t$ and $x\mid y$ $\implies x\mid z+t $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need understand these implications :

$a)$ $x,y,z,t$ natural numbers

If : $x\mid y+z+t$ and $x\mid y$ $\implies x\mid z+t $ ?

$b)$ $x,y,z,t$ natural  numbers

If : $x\mid y+z+t$ and $x\mid y$ $\implies x\mid z , x\mid t $ ?

If it's correct how I prove it ?

I know that : $x\mid y$ and $x\mid z$ then $x\mid ky+lz$

For example, we know that

$3\mid 12=9+2+1$.

We see $3\mid 2+1$

bcz $3\mid 9$

But $3\not\mid 1,2$

So $b$ is not correct

I need some explain and which correct

Comment: If $ax = y+z+t$ and $bx=y$, then $ax-bx = z+t$, but $ax-bx=(a-b)x$.

Comment: If $x|y$ then for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $y=nx$. Try to express $x,y,z,t$ in the same way, and then see what you can simplify algebraically. That's basically the only way. Always apply definition first.

Comment: @DonThousan correct or no ? Can you explain more

Comment: @jon.sand thanks I'm trying but I don't get you

Answer (score 2):

a) Is correct because in general if $a|b$ and $a|c$ then $a|b-c$. This fact is true because if $b=ka, c=ja$ for some $k,j\in \mathbb{N}$ then $b-c=(k-j)a$ so $a\mid b-c$. In your case $b=y+z+t$, $c=y$.

b) Is not correct, for example $3\mid 3+4+2$ and $3\mid 3$ but $3\not\mid 4$ and $3\not\mid 2$.

Comment: thank you very much